# Laravel project structure on server

Tags: laravel, server

I just bought a domain name for my website and linked it to my server. But now that I have transferred the files of my old free domain to my new one, I can't figure out why it redirects me to my old site and why I get the green page saying `Laravel is installed successfully.

Laravel is a Framework and doesn't have an index page.

You will be redirected to its "public" folder in 5 seconds... bla bla bla

I need some help!!

Here's the structure of my files on the server:
[image]

EDIT:

The "shlproextra" directory was too much in my directory structure. I just extract all the dir from it and put them in htdocs like this:

`|shlproextra.ca
|----htdocs
     |----app
     |----bootstrap
     |----cache
     |----config
     |----...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files should be at shlproextra.ca/, /shlproextra/ not needed

On /server.php you chance line:

require_once **DIR**.'/public/index.php';

to

require_once **DIR**.'/htdocs/index.php';

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I had that directory that I didn't need!! Now I still have this page telling me I'll be redirected to the public folder of laravel in the next 5 seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

Check APP_URL value in .env file.